# How to pass a package flag to cabal for the Haskell Language Server extension?

Tags: haskell, vscode-extensions, cabal

I'm using the HLS in VS code. I need to pass a flag (`hmatrix:openblas`) to `cabal` otherwise it fails to build the project.

I tried to add a `cabal.project` file to the project, containing `flags: openblas`, but this has not worked. I got a failure notification *'Failed to run the GHC version'* regarding the `cabal` command and then the HLS has totally stopped to work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `cabal.project` and add:

```bash
packages: . # This is an example, use the configuration which fits your codebase


# This is the part which enables the flag for hmatrix (or -openblas to disable)
package hmatrix
  flags: +openblas
```

both, `cabal` and `hls` should build the project with this flag enable. For more info, refer to the [docs](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-project.html#package-configuration-options)

Comment: I created `cabal.config` and added `flags: openblas` inside of it and it works!

Answer (score 0):

This was almost good... Use a project file `cabal.config`, not `cabal.project`, and write `flags: openblas` in this file.

Oddly, that does not work if we use the global cabal configuration file.

Comment: May I ask which version of cabal you are using?? `cabal.config` seems to be the configuration file for `v1` commands (very old version of cabal, I have never heard of such file).

Comment: @Ismor I'm using a recent version of Cabal. There's a global Cabal `.config` file and  `cabal.config` is local, placed inside the root folder of the package.

Comment: Notice cabal's [docs](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cabal-project.html#conditionals-and-imports) reference `cabal.config` as an old version of `cabal.project`. Moreover, the few references of the `cabal.config` file are related with v1 style builds. For example, command `--v1-freeze-file` uses `cabal.config` but `--v2-freeze-file` uses `cabal.project` ([docs](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cabal-commands.html#cmdoption-v1-freeze-file))

Comment: @lsmor Strange indeed. But it works like this :)